# Search key from a value in a complex json

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

I am new in angular. I have this problem: 
How search a key from a value in a json like this???

```
{"Jar1":{"class1":["method1","method2"],
               "class2": ["method2,"method3"]
              },
 "Jar2":{"class3": 
        ["method1","method2"],
 "class4":["method2,"method3]
            }
 }
```

If i have var classItem="class3" i want returned "Jar2".. how??

Thanks for help.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the JSON as a string then use standard JavaScript [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to get an object form it. And `Jar1` and `Jar2` will be properties of the object. Then the most simple solution is to iterate all the entries in the object until find the one which has a value with the class3 property. You get all entries of an object using the standard JavaScript method [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which returns all the property names and values of an object. To search the keys of the value object to determine if the object contains the class3 property you can use the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to get all the property names of an object.

Here is a sample using this approach:

```
const classItem = 'class3';
const parsedJsonObject = JSON.parse(`{
  "Jar1": { "class1": ["method1", "method2"], "class2": ["method2", "method3"] },
  "Jar2": { "class3": ["method1", "method2"], "class4": ["method2", "method3"] }
}`)
const [jarPropertyName, _] = Object.entries(parsedJsonObject).find(([_ ,jarObject]) => Object.keys(jarObject).includes(classItem));
console.log(jarPropertyName);
```

Here is also a [StackBlitz link to a working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ltdlj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: No .. json is returned json from a get service.. i think it is a simple dictionary. Var a={....}.. your code dont work :(

Comment: I added a link to a StackBlitz sample where you can see that my code works in Angular. The object you get from a get service call is what is in my sample the `parsedJsonObject`. The Angular HttpClient library parses it for you. If you posted the right JSON then what you get from the service should be exactly the same. If this does not work for you create a sample in StackBlitz to demonstrate what is the real issue. Just saying my code does not work does not give me any information to be able to help you further. Please provide more details what fails and what exactly is your code now.